# Prove that this set is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $f_1,f_2:(-1,1)\rightarrow[0,+\infty)$ and $g_1,g_2:\mathbb{R}\times[a,+\infty)\rightarrow(-1,1)$ for some $a>0$. $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2$ are all continuous functions.

Define the set
$$
S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:f_1(g_1(x_1,y))+f_2(g_2(x_2,y))\leq L,\;\;\forall y\geq a\}
$$

for some $L>0$.

Is this set closed? [I'm kinda confused by this $\forall y\geq a$]. If it isn't, can you find sufficient conditions so that it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $y\in\mathbb{R}$, consider the function
$$
h_y:x\longrightarrow f_1(g_1(x_1,y))+f_2(g_2(x_2,y))
$$
and observe it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by sum/composition of continuous functions.

Now note that
$$
S=\bigcap_{y\geq a}h_y^{-1}((-\infty,L]).
$$

Since $h_y$ is continuous and $(-\infty,L]$ is closed, each $h_y^{-1}((-\infty,L])$ is closed. Hence $S$ is closed as an intersection of closed sets.

**Facts used here:** a function is continuous, by definition, if the inverse image of every open (resp. closed) set is open (resp. closed). And by definition of a topology, an arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed, just like an arbitrary union of open sets is open.

**Note:** this $\forall y\geq a$ yields an intersection. Would this have been $\exists y\geq a$ instead, you would have got a union, which would not have necessarily been closed.

Comment: Damn, I was translating $\forall t \geq a$ as a union, and so I could not conclude closedness (this was the spot I got stuck in the first place). Thank you for your answer.